# How to send email conditional on column values in a data-frame in R?

Tags: r, email, if-statement

This is the code that I am using to send an email alert conditional on date ....Lets there is a datafarme df and it has column of dates ....If date column contains today's date , then it should send an email .....This is the code I am using ....

```
 library(lubridate)
 library(mailR)

 mydata<-data.frame(Name=c("Me","My","I"),date=c("2018-1-20","2018-2-20","2018-3-20"))
 mydata$date<-as.Date(mydata$date)


if(mydata$date==Sys.Date() {
sender <- "abc@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("abc@gmail.com","xyz@gmail.com ")
email <- send.mail(from = sender,
               to = recipients,
               subject="Sending Email via R",
               body = "It is Important",
               smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465,user.name="abc@gmail.com" , passwd="XXX",ssl=T),
               authenticate = T,
               send = T)

    }

   else email<-NULL
```

Comment: If you are having problems with coding then you should express your difficulties. `if` will only execute the consequent _if_ the first item in a vector is TRUE, which it clearly won't be for another 7 months.

Comment: Those dates are just random , what I meant was if I use the actual date , even then code was not working ....